# Simplify this code that adds string representation of class members to a List

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a bunch of code that adds the string representation of members in a class to a List.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
...
//Note: AuthModel is a custom class containing Id, Name, UserName, email, etc...
var someProperties = new List<string>();
someProperties.Add(GetMemberName((AuthModel m) => m.Id));
someProperties.Add(GetMemberName((AuthModel m) => m.UserName));
someProperties.Add(GetMemberName((AuthModel m) => m.Links));

//Note: someProperties will return List<string>(){ "Id", "UserName", "Links"}
...
...
public string GetMemberName<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> memberAccess)
{
   return ((MemberExpression)memberAccess.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

I would like to simplify

```
var someProperties= new List<string>();
someProperties.Add(GetMemberName((AuthModel m) => m.Id));
someProperties.Add(GetMemberName((AuthModel m) => m.UserName));
someProperties.Add(GetMemberName((AuthModel m) => m.Links));
```

into a one-liner.

For example, by creating and using a certain function called `GetPropertiesList` that accepts a class type and the properties that the caller wants as its parameter.

```
var someProperties = GetPropertiesList(typeof(AuthModel), (AuthModel m) => new {m.Id, m.UserName, m.Links });
//someProperties will return List<string>(){ "Id", "UserName", "Links"}
```

of course, the code above is syntactically wrong but I hope you get what I mean.

If it isn't possible, I would like to know how far I can possibly reduce this code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [nameof expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. There are 2 things wrong with this question: 1) We are missing the context of the code. Unlike Stack Overflow we like to see more code so that we can truly help you improve your coding skills  2) We review code that is working as expected, `How to` questions imply the code is not working as expected. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is you can use anonymous type like this :

```
public static string[] GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> memberAccess)
{
    var body = (NewExpression) memberAccess.Body;
    return body.Members.Select(x=> x.Name)?.ToArray();
}
```

usage :

```
var members = GetMemberName<AuthModel>((x) => new { x.Id , x.UserName, x.Links });
```